# Linux Server Apache User has Been Hacked

Tags: php, linux, apache, security, redirect

The problem I have is anything that the Apache user has access to, it will write files to those folders. So any directory with permissions 775 Apache can write to it.

I locked down the server to everything but the uploads folder, as Drupal would not be able to upload if the permissions were not 775.

Inside the upload directory hundreds of files like 3r1bk6bt.php, eh9mq4ov.php are added.
If I delete them they always come back in a day or two. So it is automated.

Additionally when this first happened, it would redirect the sites 50% of the time to spam sites. I stopped that by removing what they added to the .htaccess and index.php files and locked those files down to 640. So Apache could not write to it.

My question is what is the best way to narrow down the root of the problem? Is there common ways that a "redirect apache hack" happens?

Comment: Server should be rebuilt. You might be able to switch to the apache user and see what commands were run if history wasnt cleared.

Comment: Read this: https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: Which is worse: your site getting hacked/spammed constantly or people not being able to upload files? I would hope you could put up a maintenance message and go read only while you debug.

Comment: FYI this probably fits better on ServerFault or SuperUser. Unfortunately it's not something for Stack Overflow (it's not a programming question)